# Get form values (regular post form submit) using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, request

I have a form inside a page A, with 2 fields, user and password, the action of my form is a page B.

I would like to get the form values of the request header using javascript when the page B is loaded. Is this possible? Or something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** Expect for a few exceptions (useragent) the HTTP request headers are not available in client-side Javascript.

The only way to access the values of the POST:ed form would be to place them in the document when processing the request server side.

This however does not apply to Ajax requests, where the entire request and response are exposed to Javascript.

**But**, if the form uses the GET method the form values are encoded as query parameters and are available by parsing `window.location`.